# Decorator for Class Property in TypeScript Not Overriding Get/Set Properly for Instances

Tags: typescript, decorator

I'm trying to create a TypeScript decorator that overrides the get method for a property in a class, but I'm having trouble getting it to work for instances of the class.

Here's a simple test case:

```js
function Decorator() {
    return function (target: Object, propertyKey: string) {
        Object.defineProperty(target, propertyKey, {
            get: function () {
                return 42;
            },
        });
    };
}

export class Foo {
    @Decorator()
    bar = 0;
}

const foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo.bar);// Should output 42 but returns 0
```

Can anyone provide a solution or point me in the right direction?

I've tried replacing the target constructor with a new constructor that runs Object.defineProperty but  that didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

As the [official document](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#property-decorators) said: a property decorator can only be used to observe that a property of a specific name has been declared for a class.
So there is no way to modify the initial value in the property decorator.

Have a look at the equivalent javascript code:

```
class Foo {
    constructor() {
        this.bar = 0;
    }
}
```

A possible solution is to use a class decorator.

```
function Decorator() {
  return function (target: any) {
    return class extends target {
      bar = 42;
    };
  };
}

@Decorator()
class Foo {
  bar = 0;
}

const foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo.bar); // 42
```

If you really want to specify the property key, you can use a property decorator to record the property keys.

```
const KEYS = Symbol('propertyKey');

function Decorator() {
  return function (Target: any) {
    return function () {
      const target = new Target();
      const keys = target[KEYS] || [];
      for (const key of keys) {
        target[key] = 42;
      }
      return target;
    } as typeof Target;
  };
}

function PropertyDecorator() {
  return function (target: any, propertyKey: string) {
    target[KEYS] = target[KEYS] || [];
    target[KEYS].push(propertyKey);
  };
}

@Decorator()
class Foo {
  @PropertyDecorator()
  bar = 0;

  baz = 0;
}

const foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo.bar); // 42
console.log(foo.baz); // 0
```

Answer (score 0):

When `bar` is initialized , the setter method should also be degined.

```
function Decorator() {
  return function (target: Object, propertyKey: string) {
    let value
    Object.defineProperty(target, propertyKey, {
      get: function () {
        return 42
      },

      // add
      set: function (v) {
        value = v
      },

    })
  }
}
```

Another option is define bar as one of these:

```
bar: undefined
```

```
bar: any
```